# Editing of recently closed questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing

We don't have many problems with that here admittedly, but I thought that I would share this with you all.

From SuperUser - [Editing of recently closed questions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13646/editing-of-recently-closed-questions):

> This post is basically to share something I came across on Meta Unix &
>   Linux. Kusalananda♦, a moderator there, posted [Editing questions
>   recently put on hold (don't)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5319/85417). The gist is something that I don't
>   think is common knowledge, and it would be beneficial to apply the
>   same logic here.
>
> It is common knowledge that editing an on-hold post automatically
>   bumps it into the Reopen review queue. But there are two factors that
>   may not be common knowledge:
>
> - That only happens within the first five days of closure.
> - It only happens once.
>
> There are a number of implications.
>
> 1. The five day limitation means that you can **time your minor edits** on closed posts so they don't unnecessarily force wasteful
>      reviews. If you want to do tag cleanup or make minor English or
>      formatting fixes that don't address the closure issue, wait until
>      after the five days.
> 2. If you edit and fix the closure issue on a question closed more than five days, you need to **also vote to reopen** to get it into the
>      queue.
> 3. The bumping happening only once was the impetus for Kusalananda♦'s post. If you edit the recently closed post to do minor polish that
>      doesn't solve the closure issue, that bumps it to the Reopen review
>      queue where it will waste a bunch of reviewers' time and won't result
>      in it being reopened. But that also **uses up the one automatic
>      bump**.
>
>    Then, when the OP or another user actually fixes the post, that
>      will not bump it into the review queue. Unless someone explicitly
>      jump-starts the review process by voting to reopen the question (which
>      typically isn't a requirement), the post will remain closed and
>      potentially be deleted, even though it's been turned into an
>      acceptable question.
> 4. If you are going to fix a recently closed question, make sure you **fix every issue**. Questions often have multiple problems and just one may be stated as the close reason. Review the question to identify
>      everything that is a potential close reason, and address them all.
>      Otherwise, you might fix only one of the problems and the question
>      will not be reopened due to the remaining problems. That puts it right
>      back at point #3.
>
> **Bottom line**: if a question is recently closed, do not edit it until after the five days unless the edit will solve all closure
>   issues.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but doesn't the OP have the opportunity to VTR their own post after they believe they've fixed something? Parts of what you pasted here doesn't make logical sense to me.

Comment: I'm not sure, it's been a while since I've tried to reopen a closed post. I had a view closed recently on Electronics.SE but I think that the on-hold period has finished now... so I can't check.